# Problem involving a probability function that consists two functions, and the input to each function.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I was trying to solve this problem:
$f(x) = k[\phi (x) + \lambda g(X)]$
Where:
$\phi(x)$ is a normal distribution with mean =0 and variance =1.
$g(x)$ is defined as:
$\frac{1}{\lambda}$ for $ \leq x \leq \lambda $
0, otherwise.
SO, my question is, if we want to find the value of k, I would take the C.D.F of $f(x)$ to find the value of k in terms of $\lambda$.
When we are taking C.D.F, there are two options available:
$F(X)=k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) dx + k\lambda \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)$ or:
$F(X)=k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) dx + k\lambda \int_{0}^{\lambda} g(x)$.

So, I looked at the mark scheme, it chose the second integrals to get the F(x), my question is, why is that so? I dun quite understand why we can put different limits on it, its like both functions are having different inputs.
Thank you very much for you guy's replies.

Comment: You want $k$ to be such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f = 1$.

Comment: If $g(x)$ is defined as $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ for $0 \leq x \leq \lambda $ and $0$ otherwise, then  $ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)\, dx =  \int\limits_{0}^{\lambda} g(x)\, dx$ and both are $1$

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f = 1$ as it should be a density function.
We get $$ 1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f = k\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi + \lambda \int_{-\infty}^\infty g \bigg]  = k[1+ \lambda]$$ cause both $\phi$ and $g$ are density functions.
Then $$k = \frac {1}{\lambda+1}$$